# git push difference of branch with master

Tags: git, github, push, branch

Assume a new local branch named debug and the master is already pushed to the origin. 99% of the debug branch is the same as the master branch.
when I use `git push -u origin debug`, it begins to upload the whole about 1 gig project.
Is it possible instead of uploading the whole 1gig project as a new branch, just upload the changed files and copy(or maybe clone or reuse) the rest files from the master which is already uploaded?

Comment: As long as you're using the "smart" transport protocol—and GitHub do that—this is already the case in general. There are some specific exceptions, that should be rare. Are you using a shallow clone? (This might trigger one of the exceptions.) The most likely case is that you committed the addition of a big file perhaps followed by the deletion of that same big file—in which case Git must push the big file's contents as they're required by the intermediate commit.

Comment: no shallow clone! just used the regular `git branch <branch-name>` @torek

Comment: If all you did was create a new branch name pointing to an existing commit, `git push` should be very quick: your Git will call up their Git, say "I need you to have commit H" (for some hash H), and they will say "I have H, don't send it." Your Git will then say: "OK, you now have everything; please create the name `debug` pointing to commit H." They should either say "ok, done" or "I won't because ____" (fill in the blank) and the conversation should terminate at this point.

Comment: In this case, however, `debug` is **100%** the same as `master`. You said "99%". Where do you believe this other 1% comes from?

Comment: after making the debug branch, I have did debug 6 files. @torek

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is nothing you can do. Git will send only what's is necessary to be send. So it there is a lot of data being transferred, then it means you made many changes (at least from git's perspective).

As you are talking about 1GB of data I guess there are binary files in your repository.
If that's true you may consider to use git LFS feature. That should help you in the future but won't help you now (unless you rewrite whole git history).